# Email logo file path incorrect

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates, ce-1.9.2.4

So I'm running Magento 1.9.2.4 and configuring custom email templates for invoice and order emails, however when I set the logo for the email header in *system > design > transaction email* the HTML is drawing the logo instead from file path:

```
/store/skin/frontend/base/default/images/logo_email.gif
```

All other images such as the favicon are being drawn from my custom template file path, but its just this logo, it seems, is generating an incorrect URL. I know the base folder is like the fallback, so is there a reason the url would redirect to the base?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue fixed, seemed there was a problem with the custom email templates. I reset the email templates to default which fixed the issue and the URL was drawn correctly.